# How does mirror registry work in docker?

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-registry

I want to deploy the [registry mirror](https://docs.docker.com/articles/registry_mirror/) in docker, and it can avoid a trip out to the internet to refetch it. So, I use command:

```
docker pull ubuntu
docker rmi ubuntu
```

I guess that there is ubuntu image in my local.So, I closed my Internet, then use command:

```
docker pull ubuntu
```

But,it didn't work. I don't know what happened. I want to know how mirror work. May it need to connect docker hub to get dependence? or May I fail to deploy the mirror?

By the way, how to know whether I succeed in deploying mirror?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your docker daemon was started with `docker --registry-mirror=http://<my-docker-mirror-host> -d`, or none of the `docker pull` call would go through your mirror.

And of course, make sure there is one running mirror registry container (`docker ps -a`)

The [OP v11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3048805/v11) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468218/how-does-mirror-registry-work-in-docker/31469379#comment50905222_31469379):

> I think I fail to start mirror. Thanks! it maybe I don't started with docker --registry-mirror=http:// -d

The OP did modify the `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` [as advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31456344/6309), but might not have restart boot2docker before the mirror tests.

Comment: I have use command it show me it's running,but i want to know whether mirror is running, I can pull existing image without Internet? Does it need to connect docker hub to download depandence?

Comment: @v11 did you test your mirror, as described in https://docs.docker.com/articles/registry_mirror/#test-it-out? The first pull need indeed to connect to the internet. The second one should not.

Comment: Is it just time different? But, it used about 3min in first time, and  2min in second time, and 3min in third time. So I have no idea about it.

Comment: The second/third pull should be shorter. If you cut your internet access, the second/thrid should also still work.

Comment: @v11 that is the idea, yes (if your docker daemon was started before with the right `--registry-mirror` option).

Comment: Oh,I see. I think I fail to start mirror. Thanks! it maybe I don't started with docker --registry-mirror=http://<my-docker-mirror-host> -d. But, I have added to profile in this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453813/how-to-create-docker-registry-mirror

Comment: Are you sure that I can pull existing image in mirror without Internet? I have create mirror, and when I pull image, it can find in local mirror path what I set. But, I can't pull image without internet. May mirror need to docker hub to request dependency?

Comment: @v11 if one of the base images is missing in the mirror, then it tries Internet.

Comment: @v11 But if that is still not working, don't hesite to make a new question in which you would detail your setup and the scenario which fails to download without internet.